# cython mixed data types np.ndarray

Tags: numpy, cython

I am creating numpy.ndarrays in cython and wanted to see if there was any way to return to use mixed data types of ints and floats in the definition which would always return an array of both ints and floats defined by the dtype.

in all of the docs it says to declare type in the manner of:

```
cdef nd.ndarray[dtype, dim] my_func(x):
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by *"mixed data types"* - do you mean that the dtype of the returned array might be either float or int depending on the input arguments, or do you actually want a single output numpy array that contains both floats and ints?

Comment: Are you thinking about a structured array type of `dtype`?

Comment: I have a structured dtype that is a mix of ints and floats